# Polars : Running polars expression on list elements for row level manipulations - how to apply when then otherwise on arr.eval

Tags: python-polars

**Input dataframe**  my polars | pandas dataframe looks like this

| Column x | Column y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [mike,kim] |
| 2 | [ken,nate,lara] |

**Ask: Create word vectors in column z by iterating over the name lists in each row using polars; **

**Expected Output dataframe from polars**

| Column x | Column y | Column z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [mike,kim] | [[0.0001,0.0008],[0.0001,0.0008]] |
| 2 | [ken,nate,lara] | [[0.0001,0.0008],[0.0001,0.0008] |

Here i'm trying to iterate over the names in the each row, column y from input dataframe , if the name exists in the model_vocab_list get the word vectors for the name otherwise create a empty vector,

**I was hoping the below expression would do that, but it is erroring out -  'Expr' object is not iterable,  having challenge in getting the expression to work, any idea how to get it to work to get the above output**

```
expression= 
pl.when(pl.element().is_in(model_vocab_list )).then(name_model.wv[pl.element()]).otherwise(np.zeros(name_model.wv.vector_size, dtype="float32"))

pl_df = df_pl.with_columns(
    pl.col('y')
).select([
    pl.col('*'),
    pl.col("y").arr.eval(expression, parallel=True).alias("z")
])
```

**Working code in pandas to get the above output**

```
ddf['z'] = ddf['y'].apply(lambda x: [model.wv[word] if word in model_vocab_list else np.zeros(model.wv.vector_size, dtype="float32") for word in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `name_model.wv[pl.element()]` would cause that error.

- `pl.element()` only has a value inside the "polars expression engine" and `name_model.wv` only exists outside of it.

Ideally, you would create a dataframe so you could use `.join` to match the values.

Something like:

```
zero = pl.Series([pl.zeros(model.vector_size)])

vectors = pl.DataFrame(
   {
      "Column y": model.wv.key_to_index.keys(), 
      "vector": model.wv.vectors
   }
)
```

You could then `.explode` the list column, `.join` and fill in the zeros.

```
(df
 .explode("Column y")
 .join(vectors, on="Column y", how="left")
 .with_columns(vector = 
    pl.when(pl.col("vector").is_null())
      .then(zero)
      .otherwise(pl.col("vector")))
)
```

You can add `.groupby("Column x").all()` to rebuild the lists.

Comment: thank you, this is helpful. Have a follow up question, if i have a column with single values in the list, is there a way to get the item out of the list without using the explode option? Example from  Column Z  [10] to Column Z  10 or Column X ['life'] to column X life

Comment: @user1753372 Get out in what context? Perhaps you could show an example of what you mean, or post it as a new question.